# request for information already sent

Tags: professionalism, email

I have sent someone an e-mail containing information (link, document, etc.), but they ask for it again as though I had never sent it to them.

Is it **unprofessional** to forward them the original e-mail with the information and their address in the `To:` or `Cc:` field?

Comment: Not only is it NOT unprofessional, it is often the only correct way to do it. To do otherwise complicates the timeline and the last thing you want is any doubt over whether or not you sent the original message.

Comment: Did this happen just once, or is it a regular thing with this person?  The answer should have a big impact on how you react.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it is not unprofessional to forward the original e-mail.

Make sure that your original e-mail contains all the information they requested.
In the forwarding e-mail, you write something like,

> > Dear Mr./Ms. *name*,
> >
> > I am forwarding the e-mail I sent to you earlier in case it did not reach you in the first place.
> >
> > Thanks.
> >
> > Your name

The forwarding e-mail should then include the time/date of the original e-mail and the original e-mail which has all the information they requested.

Comment: **Comments removed.** Please use [chat] (rather than comments) for extended discussion.

Answer (score 16):

**In General**

Yes. If you've sent it once, it's better to send complete with the header information, and date and time it was sent (just forward the original e-mail to them, that will contain everything).

**However...**

Lots of people are prickly, and the above approach may insult them. There are many times when it's better to resend it without forwarding the whole e-mail for the sake of civility and/or saving yourself a headache.

Some rules of thumb:

- **Do** forward it if it is time-sensitive information (so you don't get blamed for delays)
- **Do** forward it it's a coworker who you're training and shouldn't lose the e-mail in the first place
- **Don't** forward it if it's an estimate to a client and their boss was CC'd (making someone with purchasing power look bad to his boss is bad form)
- **Don't** forward it if it's your boss and other coworkers are CC'd (your boss doesn't want to look bad in front of the other coworkers)

**Disclaimer**

These are all just rules of thumb. Use good judgment. Generally speaking, the idea is that you want to protect yourself first, but not protect yourself from marginal risk at the expense of making the other person look bad, especially in front of their boss/coworkers.

Comment: `Lots of people are prickly, and the above approach may insult them.` They have no right to be insulted because they most likely didn't even bother searching for the original email in the first place, yet they expect **you** to write them a brand new email as if the first one never happened?  The implication of feeling prickly about this is the most condescending, arrogant and hypocritical mindset imaginable! The receiver implicitly communicates that his time is vastly more important than yours, so you must cater to my requests.

Comment: Yes, some people in business are unreasonable. And lazy. And a pain to deal with. And many of those people are customers or bosses who are best served not irking when not required. Right or not, they will be insulted, and you will have to deal with the consequences. My suggestion is to avoid the hassle. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @maple_shaft Maybe their time **is** more important than yours? If a VP of an MNC asks a tech lead for some info in a mailing list, the tech lead should send it rather than forwarding them a link to some documentation or a previous email. The person in question might be juggling all sorts of things with very tight timelines and might just need a hand.

Comment: @MrFox If their time is more important, then sending a reminder that they already had it will save them more of their important time, the next time.  Sending an email isn't exactly a no-time task, nor is waiting on the reply.

Comment: @maple_shaft in business, especially when dealing with clients, you don't always have the luxury of being able to piss people off with no repercussions.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Would you rather receive an e-mail within an e-mail with a bunch of additional information you aren't asking for, or just the document you need? Which is more time efficient? For the sender, finding the file and finding the e-mail will take the same amount of time. For the reader, sending just the file will be far more appreciated.

Comment: @jmac It is only more efficient from _your_ point of view; however, if you consistently make it apparent that only your efficiency matters _at the expense of others_ those others will realize that you don't value them, and will eventually not be willing to put forth their effort _for you_.  For the sender, if it was really time critical, a quick search of their emails (the search engines are not bad) probably amounts to less time than the email query anyway.

Comment: @jmac This ask but forget, indicates that the original effort wasn't really important to the requester (or it wouldn't be so easily lost), and having them re-request items often is a sort of learned helplessness which involves the requester not even imagining that they could act themselves (by caring a bit more about whatever it is that they claimed was needed).

Comment: Perhaps we work in very different companies @EdwinBuck, but in my company people get CC'd on e-mails all the time and ignore them because the volume is massive, and the content is generally not relevant to what they're doing at the moment (especially for bosses). Perhaps you get very little e-mail directly to you, and can keep track of it all. Many people, especially in management, aren't as lucky, and assuming that it's laziness, helplessness or other malice isn't going to help in the long run.

Comment: @jmac I get far too much email, but take it upon my shoulders to not add wood to the fire.  I see, firing off an email that asks for something before searching to see if I have it already as shirking my duty to be a respectful human being.  Others have their own opinion, but as long as you don't dismiss them (their time isn't valuable compared to _me_) they'll respect your opinion.  Nobody lives up to a standard if they are not challenged with one, and rewarding bad behavior is a sure fire way to get more bad behavior.